# Rollback or commit on a transaction with just a SELECT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I wonder if it is somehow different to end a transaction with ROLLBACK or COMMIT in case there were only SELECT command(s) inside it.
have a pseudo-code like this:

```
using (var tr = new TransactionScope())
{
    if (!GetData(condition).Any()) // SELECT command behind
    {
      InsertData();  // INSERT command

      tr.Commit();
      return true;
    }

    tr.Commit(); // Or rollback?
    return false;
}
```

Are there any performance penalties in either case or it does not matter?

Comment: Your example looks like it performs an insert (`InsertData()`)...

Comment: Do the select commands lock data?

Comment: What would there be to rollback in select statement?

Answer (score 1):

Commit says "make any data modifications that I've done in the scope of this transaction durable". Rollback says "undo any data modifications that I've made in the scope of this transaction". In the case of a select, no data modifications have been made and so both commit and rollback do the same thing (which is to release whatever locks were held after the select completed).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your InsertData does inserts based okut the output of GetData:

General cleanup

```
using (var tr = new TransactionScope())
{
    if (!GetData(condition).Any()) // SELECT command behind
    {
      InsertData();  // INSERT command
      tr.Complete()
      return true;
    }

    return false;
    // rollback will be automatic if complete isn't called
}
```

More performant:

```
if (!GetData(condition).Any()) // SELECT command behind
{
  // implied transaction within the InsertData method.
  InsertData();  // INSERT command
  return true;
}

return false;
```